# Understanding correlation between estimated class probabilities for multinomial distribution

Tags: correlation, binomial-distribution, standard-error

Suppose that I estimate class probabilities for a multinomial distribution with three classes using individual binomial confidence intervals. I'd like to create a confidence interval the error around the value of a linear combination of these estimates. In particular, if the value of an outcome in each class is different (but deterministic), I'd like to understand the average outcome value. So if $X_i \sim Normal(\hat{p}_i, \sigma_{\hat{p}_i}^2)$, I want to understand the distribution of,

$$
Y = aX_1 + bX_2 + cX_3
$$

I know that the distribution of $Y$ will be normal, and the mean of this distribution is straightforward. My issue comes from the fact that I think that I need to understand the covariance structure between the errors on my estimates of the class probabilities in order to calculate the variance of it, and I'm unsure how to do that. Could anyone give me advice on how this should be done?

Comment: You mention three different distributions: multimodal, binomial, and normal. Which one exactly is your likelihood and what is the model?

Comment: @Tim Sorry for the confusion. I have confidence intervals for the class probabilities of the multinomial distribution. This was done using binomial confidence intervals, e.g., if the probability of the third class is $p_3$, then I calculate it as a binomially distributed random variable with probability of success $p_3$ and failure $1 - p_3$.

Given the three confidence intervals, where each was defined assuming a normal distribution of the estimated class probability about the true one, I'd like to come up with a confidence interval about the mean of $Y$ as defined in the question.

Comment: So my point estimate of the mean value would be $a * \hat{p}_1 + b * \hat{p}_2 + c * \hat{p}_3$, but I'd like to propagate the error around my estimates of $p_i$ forward as well. My struggle is understanding how the correlation between my different estimates of the class probabilities tie together